# Apps don't see adoptable storage anymore

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

My adopted storage Micro SD card (Samsung EVO+ 64GB) doesn't get detected by any apps anymore, but it has worked with that same SD and exact phone (Moto G3) before.

I don't see how it would work either, since the `/storage/emulated partition` (yes, I highlighted the wrong line) shows that it is in fact only 11.8 GB. The only partitions that are close to 64GB are the `/mnt/expand/*` directories and those are not accessible.

Is there some sort of "hidden option" that I turned off by accident?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the "Storage & USB" Settings, click the SD card and in the top right corner there are three vertical dots. Click on those and then "Migrate data". This fixed the issue for me.